# Is there any tool available to LaTeX to search for files with wildcards?

Tags: external-files

Say I want to find all of the packages of the form

```
tikzlibrary*.code.tex
```

Is there any way I can retrieve a list of all such files available in TeX's path in a portable way, hopefully one that doesn't require a special compilation sequence?

<sub>My actual task has nothing to do with TikZ—so TikZ-specific answers will probably not work.</sub>

Comment: Related [kpsewhich: Standalone path searching and its use with examples in TeXLive doc](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-650007.2.2)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you restrict to packages that have been hashed by [kpathsea](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/kpathsea) path searching library then you can do

```
grep "tikzlibrary.*code\.tex" `kpsewhich --all ls-R`
```

replacing grep by any plain text file searching tool if you are on a machine without grep. `kpsewhich`  is used as a standalone front-end of the `kpathsea` library

```
$ grep "tikzlibrary.*code\.tex" `kpsewhich --all ls-R`
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarybayesnet.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrary3d.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryautomata.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarybackgrounds.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarycalendar.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarychains.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarydecorations.footprints.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarydecorations.fractals.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarydecorations.markings.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarydecorations.shapes.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarydecorations.text.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryer.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryfadings.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryfit.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryfixedpointarithmetic.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryfolding.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryfpu.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryintersections.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarylindenmayersystems.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarymindmap.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarypatterns.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarypetri.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryplothandlers.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryscopes.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryshadings.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryshadows.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryshapes.arrows.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryshapes.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryshapes.gates.logic.IEC.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryshapes.gates.logic.US.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryshapes.misc.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarysnakes.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryspy.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarysvg.path.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarythrough.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarytrees.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryturtle.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarycircuits.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarycircuits.ee.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarycircuits.ee.IEC.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarycircuits.logic.CDH.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarycircuits.logic.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarycircuits.logic.IEC.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarycircuits.logic.US.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarydatavisualization.3d.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarydatavisualization.barcharts.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarydatavisualization.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarydatavisualization.formats.functions.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarydatavisualization.polar.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarydatavisualization.sparklines.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarygraphs.basic.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarygraphs.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarypgfplots.colormaps.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarypgfplots.dateplot.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarypgfplots.external.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarypgfplots.groupplots.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarypgfplots.patchplots.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarypgfplots.polar.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarypgfplots.smithchart.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarypgfplots.statistics.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarypgfplots.ternary.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarypgfplots.units.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_tikzlibraryexternal.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarydateplot.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryhobby.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryocgx.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryexternal.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryshadows.blur.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarypgfplots.clickable.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarypgfplotsclickable.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryrulercompass.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryswitching-architectures.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarycalligraphy.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibraryknots.code.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R:tikzlibrarytikzmark.code.tex
```

Comment: +1 I was disappointed when I found I couldn't feed `kpsewhich` a regex directly and so looked at `tlmgr` instead. But yours sill find more stuff if you've got relevant files in the local tree.

Comment: i think you've got a glitch in your `grep` statement -- need to invert the `.*` to `*.` -- but i'm not about to change *your* code!

Comment: @barbarabeeton no it's a regex not a filename glob `library*.` would look for a sequence of 0 or more `y`

Answer (score 8):

This is dependent on TeX Live but does not require `grep`:

```
tlmgr search --file '.*tikzlibrary.*\.code\.tex'
```

produces:

```
aobs-tikz:
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/aobs-tikz/tikzlibraryoverlay-beamer-styles.code.tex
hobby:
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/hobby/tikzlibraryhobby.code.tex
ocgx:
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/ocgx/tikzlibraryocgx.code.tex
pgf:
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/circuits/tikzlibrarycircuits.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/circuits/tikzlibrarycircuits.ee.IEC.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/circuits/tikzlibrarycircuits.ee.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/circuits/tikzlibrarycircuits.logic.CDH.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/circuits/tikzlibrarycircuits.logic.IEC.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/circuits/tikzlibrarycircuits.logic.US.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/circuits/tikzlibrarycircuits.logic.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/datavisualization/tikzlibrarydatavisualization.3d.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/datavisualization/tikzlibrarydatavisualization.barcharts.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/datavisualization/tikzlibrarydatavisualization.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/datavisualization/tikzlibrarydatavisualization.formats.functions.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/datavisualization/tikzlibrarydatavisualization.polar.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/datavisualization/tikzlibrarydatavisualization.sparklines.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/graphs/tikzlibrarygraphs.basic.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/graphs/tikzlibrarygraphs.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary3d.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryautomata.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarybackgrounds.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarycalendar.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarychains.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.footprints.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.fractals.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.markings.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.shapes.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.text.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryer.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryfadings.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryfit.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryfixedpointarithmetic.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryfolding.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryfpu.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryintersections.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarylindenmayersystems.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarymindmap.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarypatterns.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarypetri.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryplothandlers.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryscopes.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshadings.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshadows.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.arrows.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.gates.logic.IEC.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.gates.logic.US.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.misc.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarysnakes.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryspy.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarysvg.path.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarythrough.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytrees.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryturtle.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/libraries/tikzlibraryexternal.code.tex
pgf-blur:
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf-blur/tikzlibraryshadows.blur.code.tex
pgfplots:
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarypgfplots.colormaps.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarypgfplots.dateplot.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarypgfplots.external.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarypgfplots.groupplots.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarypgfplots.patchplots.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarypgfplots.polar.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarypgfplots.smithchart.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarypgfplots.statistics.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarypgfplots.ternary.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarypgfplots.units.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_tikzlibraryexternal.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfplotscompatib/tikzlibrarydateplot.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarypgfplots.clickable.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarypgfplotsclickable.code.tex
rulercompass:
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/rulercompass/tikzlibraryrulercompass.code.tex
sa-tikz:
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/sa-tikz/tikzlibraryswitching-architectures.code.tex
spath3:
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/spath3/tikzlibrarycalligraphy.code.tex
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/spath3/tikzlibraryknots.code.tex
tikz-bayesnet:
        texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-bayesnet/tikzlibrarybayesnet.code.tex
tikzmark:
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikzmark/tikzlibrarytikzmark.code.tex
```

Unlike David Carlisle's solution, though, this won't pick up stuff from the local `texmf` tree.

[I think it is kind of neat you can do this with `tlmgr`, though, so I'm posting it anyway.]

Comment: +1 also of course your version actually shows the paths:-) (I could use some more arcane commandline to extract the full path from ls-R listings, but in oractice I'd just look in an editor..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If you just want the names of the files, though, that might be seen as a disadvantage! I guess it depends what you are doing with it. I kind of like that it shows me the package names, too. But again, that might be another complication if you are trying to parse it in a script.